# Make git undo any whitespace-only changes?

Tags: git

Is there an easy way to automatically do a git checkout on any file that only has whitespace changes? I'm dealing with both Windows and some code generation that's run from Eclipse, so I get newline changes and whitespace changes that are clogging up my workflow with noise, and making it difficult to track actual changes.

Even just a nice way to *report* which files have real changes and which don't would be a start, rather than having to do a diff -w for each one

Comment: This has been answered (note that while the question says only line endings, the answer uses diff -b which is "Ignore changes in the amount of white space"): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027584/how-to-git-reset-all-files-whose-only-difference-is-lineendings

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to "git reset" all files whose only difference is lineendings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027584/how-to-git-reset-all-files-whose-only-difference-is-lineendings)

Comment: related: [Git add only non-whitespace changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515597/git-add-only-non-whitespace-changes)

Answer (score 156):

### If your changes are not staged

To stage changes that are not just whitespace changes, you can do:

`git diff -U0 -w --no-color | git apply --cached --ignore-whitespace --unidiff-zero -`

Afterwards, to remove all unstaged changes (those changes that differ only in whitespace), you can do:

`git checkout .`

### If your changes are staged

Unstage your changes by doing a `git reset --mixed` and continue from the top of this answer. Note that `mixed` is the default mode and can be omitted.

Comment: I had a load of files copied down from an FTP to see what was different between my local repo and the remote host, and all the files had different line endings, making it very tedious to identify non-whitespace changes. This worked a treat to identify the one's that were actually different.

Comment: At first, this didn't work for me because I wasn't in the root directory of the repository (even though it should not be requirement to be in the root directory, I think). So, in case `git apply` returns success (0) without doing anything, try going to the repository's root.

Comment: Note that if you have `diff.noprefix = true`, the `git apply` above will fail. To fix it, add the option `-p0`.

Comment: This saved me a billion years... one caveat in my case - it doesn't ignore complete blank lines added/removed. To include that, add `--ignore-blank-lines` to the diff.

Comment: If your changes are commited (and belong exactly to last commit), you can do: ```git reset --soft HEAD~1``` to make them staged, and then follow the instructions above.

Comment: Those who are lazy do not forget to use an alias like:
`clearws = !git diff -U0 -w --no-color | git apply --cached --ignore-whitespace --unidiff-zero - && git checkout .`

Comment: Explain every token of these commands.

Comment: Thank you for this - after trying bunch of other stuff, this worked like a charm for my case, which included a large number of files.

Comment: A default option such as `git reset --mixed --line-endings` would be really helpful to reset line ending changes automatically.

Answer (score 10):

This is most likely a line ending issue; Windows uses CRLF (carriage return + line feed, or `\r\n`) line endings, whereas most other systems use LF (line feed, or `\n`). Luckily, Git can normalize files such that they are *always* stored as LF in the repo, but will be checked out as CRLF on Windows. You can do this by setting `core.autocrlf` to `true` on Windows:

```
$ git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

and setting `core.autocrlf` to `input` on Mac and Linux:

```
$ git config --global core.autocrlf input
```

More info is available [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20121122105231/http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-1.html#Formatting-and-Whitespace) (scroll down to the section titled **core.autocrlf**).

Comment: I know *why* it's doing it, and I know about core.autocrlf and have it set to true. Neither of these things make it easy to throw away whitespace-only changes made by code generation (such as GraniteDS' plugin spitting out unix newlines even on Windows)

Comment: @moonlightcheese: They changed the Git webpage a few years ago, and apparently got some of the redirects wrong. I updated the URL.

Answer (score 7):

### If your changes are commited

(there’s probably a smarter way but this works for me)

```
mybranch=master
git checkout -b tmp origin/master

# compute the non-ws diff to mybranch and apply it
git diff -U0 -w --no-color $mybranch | git apply -R --cached --ignore-whitespace --unidiff-zero -

git commit -m "non ws changes"
git reset --hard  # discard all non-staged data
```

Your now on a new "tmp" branch. You may want to clean up (NOTE: this loses history of `$mybranch`)

```
git checkout $mybranch
git reset --hard tmp
git branch -D tmp
```

Comment: `git commit -C "$mybranch"` to reuse old message.

Comment: Also this solution seems to imply that `master` is one commit ahead of `origin/master`. If that's not the case, just checkout `master~1` instead.  After applying changes, just override `master` with `git checkout -B master`.  The temporary branch is also just optional.

Answer (score 2):

**If your changes are commited and pushed...**

...and you are not comfortable with advanced git command line use, but have access to [JetBrains Rider IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/) or JB family of tools in general, doing mixed git reset via GUI automatically removes whitespace changes. Then just commit. From 200+ files, it only missed one, which I can revert manually.

This procedure can be done 99% via GUI. Right click on base branch in the Git tab, and do reset. It will undo the commit and stage non-whitespaces changes for commit. Now commit and push -f (I always force push via command line). That's it, you are done!

[image]

Comment: It does not work. It still shows whitespace changes in all files

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use dos2unix command on a unix or (windows pc as a special install) to convert the line endings and commit and push

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it like this in Powershell 5.1:

```bash
# Unstage all pending changes 
git reset

# Create a hashtable to store the files to undo
# By inserting all the files with changes (including whitespace only)
# And then removing the files with real changes 
# Note -w flag indicates to not include whitespace only changes
$files = @{}
git diff --numstat | % { $files.Add($_.Split("`t")[2], $_) }
git diff -w --numstat | % { $files.Remove($_.Split("`t")[2]) }

# Undo the changes
$files.keys | % { git checkout -- $_ }
```

Answer (score -1):

[rumpel's answer](http://#answer-59938552) was the right fix for me. I would just like to complete a bit :

**If your changes have been pushed**

Once you followed rumpel's procedure, **do not push again on your branch**. Github will ask you to pull before and you will get every whitespace diff again. Instead create a new branch from your current branch and push the new one :

```
# From $mybranch
git checkout -b $mybranch-v2
git push --set-upstream origin $mybranch-v2
```

Then on GitHub close and delete $mybranch

Comment: i don't see any reason not to forcefully push your own branch if you discussed that with your team